# Install old version of PHP on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, php, installation

I am trying to install PHP 5.2.17 on a CentOS machine.  Having problems as I have only used `yum` in the past.

I have the file downloaded and unpacked... not clear on how I need to `./configure` before using the `make` and `make install`.

UPDATE: I am getting this message when installing php 5.2.17 from a fresh cloud instance:

```
# rpm -ivh php-5.2.17-1.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies: libaspell.so.15()(64bit) is needed by
php-5.2.17-1.x86_64 libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by
php-5.2.17-1.x86_64 libcurl.so.3()(64bit) is needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64
libpspell.so.15()(64bit) is needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64
libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64 php-cli = 5.2.17-1 is
needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64
```

I ended up installing PHP 5.3 on this instance which of addressed some of the above.  However now I am wrestling with `php-cli` and `php-common` which are failing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to install anything that is older than PHP 5.3? I mean: 5.4 is „near“

Comment: I understand fully...Have taken on a new site that is running an older version and have no choice at this point. Migrating later...have to deal with some things first. I know..it sucks.

Comment: Sorry about that..I did actually spend a good bit of time trying before posting here.  Thank you for the link though...however it fails on the second step with this message:

Comment: ]# rpm -ivh php-5.2.17-1.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libaspell.so.15()(64bit) is needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64
        libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64
        libcurl.so.3()(64bit) is needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64
        libpspell.so.15()(64bit) is needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64
        libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64
        php-cli = 5.2.17-1 is needed by php-5.2.17-1.x86_64

Comment: you should put that in your question and not as a comment.

Comment: Why the CentOS 6 requirement? You are building an unstable system. CentOS 5 would be a better choice.

Comment: Yeah I am actually trying now and still dealing with missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that running older versions of PHP is easiest done on older versions of Linux that have older versions of php out of the box...I used an older version of Ubuntu and got the job done.

Thanks all for your help!